# Convert this CSS in SCSS (same child different parents)

Tags: css, sass

I'm converting a long CSS file into SCSS and got stuck on the following piece of CSS which consists of the a child div that can have different parent divs:

```
.dark-bg li.accordion-item,
.image li.accordion-item,
.parallax li.accordion-item {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Could that be convertible to SCSS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any CSS is valid SCSS. If you rely want to make more like SCSS, you could write:

```
.dark-bg, .image, .parallax {
  li.accordion-item {
    margin: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ok?

```
@mixin hasAccordion() {
    & li.accordion-item {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.dark-bg, .image, parallax {
   @include hasAccordion;
}
```